# How to use removeIf() to remove 2 conditions?

Tags: java, remove-if

I want to use `removeIf` to remove 2 conditions, but I did not find the proper way to do that.

For example, I want to remove students whose grade is below ‘B’

Code as follows:

```
Student[] group1 = {new Student(), new Student(), new Student(), new Student()};

group1[0].setInfo("Davut", 'M', 123, 'A');
group1[1].setInfo("Ali", 'M', 43, 'B');
group1[2].setInfo("Ivan", 'M', 34, 'B');
group1[3].setInfo("Lily", 'F', 67, 'C');

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(group1));

ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.addAll(Arrays.asList(group1));
System.out.println("--------------");
Predicate<Student> condition = p->p.grade=='C'&& p.grade=='B';
students.removeIf(condition);
```

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question. Your code should work.

Comment: if you want cleaner solution move the condition to method and use method reference in `removeIf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
Predicate<Student> condition = p->p.grade=='C'&& p.grade=='B';
```

You'r asking to remove a student that has grade 'C' **AND** 'B'. It should be 'C' **OR** 'B'.

Replace with this:

```
Predicate<Student> condition = p->p.grade=='C' || p.grade=='B';
```

Answer (score 3):

```java
Predicate<Student> condition = p->p.grade=='C'&& p.grade=='B';
students.removeIf(condition);
```

Should be

```java
Predicate<Student> condition = p->p.grade=='C'|| p.grade=='B';
students.removeIf(condition);
```

It's impossible for a student's grade to be both B and C, so the predicate you provided will never be true.

Also, it's possible to chain together two predicates with the `and()` and `or()` methods like so:

```java
Predicate<Student> condition = p->p.grade=='C'
Predicate<Student> condition2 = p->p.grade=='B';
students.removeIf(condition.or(condition2);
// students.removeIf(condition.and(condition2); works similarly but with logical and
```

https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/predicates-logical-operations/

Answer (score 0):

You also could try to do something like:

```
Predicate<Student> condition = p-> ((int) p.grade) > 65;
```

'A' char in ASCII is 65, so any letter after A, like B - 66, C - 67, D - 68 are higher.

However it is not particularly safe to do this. Because what if You pass a '@' as grade char..

I would most probably introduce a Enum with grades.
And in enum instroduce a method `isLessThenA()`
In method I would check if value is of ssome enum type and if not, would throw an Exception.

Comment: Not recommended. Too hard to read for many.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct. As an alternative, why not just two calls to `removeIf()`?

```
students.removeIf(p->p.grade=='C');
students.removeIf(p->p.grade=='B');
```

I find it clear to read, and neither you nor your reader needs to consider whether it should have been `&&` or `||`.